# How is the WordPress.org plugin download history calculated?

Tags: plugins, wordpress.org

I'm interested to know how the download history of plugins is calculated on WordPress.org.

I'm noticing that one of my plugins is displaying a small percentage of users using a version which I haven't released yet via WordPress.org. Is it because I have installed it manually on a couple of my sites for testing?

Comment: Your unreleased version has not been committed into SVN?

Comment: No it hasn't yet.

Comment: Weird - I wouldn't have thought this was possible then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've answered a similar Question: [Does the number of downloads displayed for a plug-in in the WordPress.org plug-in directory include automatic updates?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/60191/12615)

This is Otto's [blog post](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2010/10/22/new-and-improved-this-morning-we-have-a/) in make.wordpress.org with plenty of information about this stats.

Excerpts from the whole page (article and comments), worth reading in full:

> First, on the extend plugin directory, you may notice some new pie chart fun on the stats tab for each plugin. This shows a percentage breakdown of the versions being actively used by that plugin’s users. Only slices greater than 1.0% are shown.
>
> [...] it’s saving the total counts of the version numbers as reported by the plugin update-checks over the last week. Since the data at present is only from one day, it’s not very accurate.
>
> [...] the download count includes direct downloads as well
>
> [...] There is no “raw count” anywhere on that version number chart. The raw count is not data that will be made available.
>
> The numbers come from the sites where it is activated, not just installed.